# Ошибка в FXML файле "Метод обработчика недоступен. Откройте общий доступ или создайте аннотацию с помощью @FXML

Tags: java, javafx

В файле FlatWin.fxml в строчке

```
<Label onMouseClicked="#close" styleClass="close-button" text="X" />
```

есть ошибка, пишет: "Метод обработчика недоступен. Откройте общий доступ или создайте аннотацию с помощью @FXML."
Но метод есть, он описан в FlatWinController.java. И в scene builder на событие On Mouse Clicked я установил метод close.

При запуске проекта ошибка такая:

```
Executing C:\Users\Alex\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication8\dist\run2023887865\JavaFXApplication8.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onMouseClicked='#close', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
file:/C:/Users/Alex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication8/dist/run2023887865/JavaFXApplication8.jar!/net/bekwam/bkcourse/flatwinapp/FlatWin.fxml:18

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at net.bekwam.bkcourse.flatwinapp.FlatWinApp.start(FlatWinApp.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application net.bekwam.bkcourse.flatwinapp.FlatWinApp
Java Result: 1
```

Пытался сделать как написано тут: https://courses.bekwam.net/public_tutorials/bkcourse_flatwinapp_1.php

Файл FlatWinController.java

```
package net.bekwam.bkcourse.flatwinapp;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FlatWinController implements Initializable {

@FXML
public void close(MouseEvent evt) {
    ((Label)evt.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
} 

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}     
}
```

Файл WindowsHack.java

```
package net.bekwam.bkcourse.flatwinapp;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class WindowsHack {

public Scene getShadowScene(Parent p) {
Scene scene;
VBox outer = new VBox();
outer.getChildren().add( p );
outer.setPadding(new Insets(10.0d));
outer.setBackground( new Background(new BackgroundFill( 
Color.rgb(0,0,0,0), new CornerRadii(0), new
  Insets(0))));

p.setEffect(new DropShadow());
((VBox)p).setBackground( new Background(new BackgroundFill
(Color.WHITE, new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0)
)));

scene = new Scene( outer );
scene.setFill( Color.rgb(0,255,0,0) );
return scene;
}
}
```

Файл FlatWinApp.java

```
package net.bekwam.bkcourse.flatwinapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class FlatWinApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

Parent p = FXMLLoader.load(FlatWinApp.class.getResource("FlatWin.fxml"));

Scene scene = null;

String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
if( osName != null && osName.startsWith("Windows") ) {

scene = (new WindowsHack()).getShadowScene(p);
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

} else {
scene = new Scene( p );
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
}

scene.getStylesheets().add("fw.css");

primaryStage.setTitle("flatwinapp");
primaryStage.setScene( scene );
primaryStage.setMinHeight(200.0d);
primaryStage.setMinWidth(300.0d);
primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}
}
```

Файл FlatWin.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
minWidth="-Infinity" 
prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"fx:controller="net.bekwam.bkcourse.flatwinapp.FlatWinController">
<children>
  <HBox styleClass="title-bar">
     <children>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
           <children>
              <Label styleClass="title" text="Flat Win" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="20.0">
           <children>
              <Label onMouseClicked="#close" styleClass="close-button" text="X" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
     </children>
  </HBox>
  <VBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
     <children>
        <Label text="Content" />
     </children>
  </VBox>
</children>
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не та сигнатура метода `close`. Надо написать так

```
public void close(ActionEvent evt) {
    ((Label) evt.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
}
```

и тогда все заработает.

Comment: Скорее, в импорте java.awt.event.MouseEvent, а не javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent